How to get the typescript reference graph?
Is there any api from typescript to get the whole reference graph including module and variables relationship of a ts project?
For example, for a project:
// index.ts
import { add, minus as sub } from './utils';
console.log(add(1, 2), minus(3, 4));

// utils.ts
export const add = (a: number, b: number) => a + b;
export function minus(a: number, b: number) {
  return a - b;
}  

I want some output like:
{
  "index.ts": [
    {
      "module": "utils.ts",
      "variables": [
        { "name": "add", "alias": null, "location": { "start": xxx, "end": xxx } },

        { "name": "minus", "alias": "sub","location": { "start": xxx, "end": xxx } }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "utils.ts": []
}


